# Where are USB drivers stored in Windows?

Tags: usb-drive

When I formatted my whole drive and installed Windows XP SP2 (fresh installation, , no drivers were load on my system). Then I connected an empty 4GB pen drive which was already formatted, and the system showed me pop up message "Installing USB drivers..."

Since there were no drivers on that pen drive or on the system, where did that USB driver come from?

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic here. [Superuser](http://superuser.com) would be a better fit.

Comment: @ Marco : ok sir..., bt i thnk i should get answer here also.

Comment: @vabojuninho so can you elaborate on what is wrong my answer, considering you downvoted it?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about Information security within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: @Lucas Kauffman : sire ; firstly , i didn't downvoted your answer and secondly.., i want to know exactly that can i manipulate the info of usb storage drive and bind codes with that...., fo example i want a 8 Gib pendrive to display 4 Gib pendrive in my boss's computer and in the remaining 4 Gib  i can fetch cinfidential data secretely

Answer (score 1):

Windows comes pre-packaged with a lot of generic drivers. These drivers will be installed when windows sees a device which it hasn't seen before and it will map those drivers to that device.

Comment: what about if i connect latest sony pen drive to windows NT system

Comment: In the end it's still a pendrive, there are standards about how they should work. If windows NT still have the generic drivers, then it's possible that they will work (although NT is very old).